Async Tasks Stuck in waiting for activation
I wrote a simple load testing tool to send 1000 requests to a slow endpoint over two seconds. Most of the Async tasks completes but eventually the tool gets stuck as some of the tasks are stuck in the WaitingForActivation state and I can't figure out why.
Is this possibly due to thread pool thread exhaustion? Any guidance how to troubleshoot this further.
Below is my code.
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using System.Threading;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;


CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

await new Client().PerformRequestsAsync("https://www.slowendpoint.test", 1000, 1000, cts.Token);
Console.WriteLine("All Done");
public class Client
{

    public static int completedCount = 0;
    public static int headerCompletedCount = 0;
    public static int allCompletedCount = 0;
    public static int failedCompletedCount = 0;
    public async Task PerformRequestsAsync(string url, int maxConcurrency, int totalRequests, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

            try
            {
                var tasks = new List<Task>();
                for (int i = 0; i < totalRequests; i++)
                {
                    if(i==500)
                        await Task.Delay(1000);

                    // Wait to proceed until it is safe to do so
                    tasks.Add(SendAsync(url, cancellationToken));
                }

                // Wait for all tasks to complete
                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
            finally
            {
                // Release the semaphore whether success or fail
            }
        
    }

    async Task SendAsync(string url, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                // Send the request and instruct HttpClient to complete as soon as headers are read
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
                Console.WriteLine("HCC: " + Interlocked.Increment(ref headerCompletedCount) + " BCC: " + completedCount + " ACC: " + allCompletedCount + " FCC: " + failedCompletedCount);

                Console.WriteLine($"Headers received: {response.StatusCode}");

                // Now read the response body in chunks of 64 KB
                const int bufferSize = 64 * 1024; // 64 KB
                var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                var totalRead = 0;

                using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = await responseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellationToken)) > 0)
                    {
                        totalRead += bytesRead;
                        //Console.WriteLine($"Read {bytesRead} bytes this chunk, total {totalRead} bytes read.");
                        // Process the chunk as needed (omitted for brevity)
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("BCC: " + Interlocked.Increment(ref completedCount) + " HCC: " + headerCompletedCount + " ACC: " + allCompletedCount + " FCC: " + failedCompletedCount);


                Console.WriteLine("Completed reading the response.");

                Console.WriteLine("ACC: " + Interlocked.Increment(ref allCompletedCount) + " BCC: " + completedCount + " HCC: " + headerCompletedCount + " FCC: " + failedCompletedCount);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            Console.WriteLine("FCC: " + Interlocked.Increment(ref failedCompletedCount) + " BCC: " + completedCount + " HCC: " + headerCompletedCount + " ACC: " + allCompletedCount);
        }
    }
}

The program at some point freezes with output like below
The output would start with something like this
FCC: 2 BCC: 3 HCC: 997 ACC: 3 
An error occurred: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
FCC: 3 BCC: 3 HCC: 997 ACC: 3
BCC: 4 HCC: 997 ACC: 3 FCC: 3
Completed reading the response.
ACC: 4 BCC: 4 HCC: 997 FCC: 3
HCC: 998 BCC: 4 ACC: 4 FCC: 3
Headers received: OK
HCC: 999 BCC: 4 ACC: 4 FCC: 3
Headers received: OK
HCC: 1000 BCC: 4 ACC: 4 FCC: 3
Headers received: OK
BCC: 5 HCC: 1000 ACC: 4 FCC: 3
Completed reading the response.
ACC: 5 BCC: 5 HCC: 1000 FCC: 3
An error occurred: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
And then freeze with something like below
ACC: 980 BCC: 980 HCC: 1000 FCC: 5 
BCC: 981 HCC: 1000 ACC: 980 FCC: 5
Completed reading the response.
ACC: 981 BCC: 981 HCC: 1000 FCC: 5
BCC: 982 HCC: 1000 ACC: 981 FCC: 5
ACC: 982 BCC: 982 HCC: 1000 FCC: 5

var httpClient = new HttpClient() - this is not good, see Guidelines for using HttpClient and YOU'RE USING HTTPCLIENT WRONG AND IT IS DESTABILIZING YOUR SOFTWARE. Also you might consider using tools like NBomber instead of reinventing the wheel.

Hi @GuruStron I know, this is not the best practice but here it is more to enforce TLS handshake with each request. But even with reusing the same client, I get the same issue. The goal of this question is to understand this behavior. Thanks for suggesting other load testing tools.

I got an answer to my question on git hub https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/101411 I will post this as an answer a bit later

After collecting memory dump the .NET team has helped me to figure out the issue and below is the root cause of the issue

One of the tasks is waiting on the responseStream.ReadAsync. This can
theoretically take forever based on the network if you don't specify a
cancellation token. (There is a pending
ContentLengthReadStream.ReadAsync => SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync
=> Socket.ReadAsync task waiting for more data on a non-disposed Socket in your dump)
In this case EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync is waiting for the underlying
Socket read to complete. That read has no inherent timeout on its own
so the socket will wait for either:

data actually arriving
the cancellation token firing
the OS
informing us that the read failed

When you're just reading data, the OS might not detect that the
connection is down until you try to write to it. One way to do that
could be to enable socket-level TCP keep-alives.

As a workaround, I passed a cancellation token with timeout to the ReadAsync method.
var linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
timeoutCts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));

while (true)
{
    try
    {
        int bytesRead = await responseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, linkedCts.Token);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            totalRead += bytesRead;
        }
        else
        {
            break; // No more data to read, exit the loop
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timeout occurred");
        break; // Exit the loop
    }
}

For more details, see the following GitHub issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/101411

You're blasting out too many requests at once without awaiting any of them. At some point the server is going to say "this guy isn't responding, let's just shut the socket".
You need to hand off the send to the thread pool to handle, using Task.Run. This leaves you with a separate loop that can get busy adding more requests.
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < totalRequests; i++)
{
    if (i % 500 == 499)   // delay after only the first 500 or after every 500??
        await Task.Delay(1000);

    // Wait to proceed until it is safe to do so
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => SendAsync(url, cancellationToken), cancellationToken));
}

// Wait for all tasks to complete
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Consider instead using Parallel.ForAsync or Parallel.ForEachAsync
await Parallel.ForAsync(0, totalRequests,
    new ParallelOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 500,
        CancellationToken = cancellationToken,
    },
    async (i, ct) => await SendAsync(url, ct));

Furthermore, your SendAsync function is missing usings. The missing usings may also be a cause of your issue, as it doesn't guarantee proper cleanup. There is also the usage of a new HttpClient each time, which could cause socket exhaustion.
static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

Also it could be more efficient. Exactly what you are doing with that read loop is not clear, but you might be able to use stream.CopyToAsync.

TBH do not understand the purpose of Task.Run(() => SendAsync(, should not await httpClient.SendAsync(request, ... basically have the same effect (and based on the HCC: 1000 it seems to)?

Not sure what you mean, but SendAsync by itself is not awaited automatically. If you hand off to Task.Run then the threadpool awaits it for you.

@Charlieface the Parallel.ForAsync worked perfectly, while the using the task.run I got the same behavior?? what is the difference the Parallel.ForAsync has made, is it all about thread pool thread management?

Task.Run should have worked similarly, although Parallel is much better.

@Charlieface, too many requests at once without awaiting any of them - not awaiting a task doesn't mean it had not been run. It is fire-and-forget , for concurrency.

I don't get the necessity too for Task.Run(() => SendAsync) in the loop. Why to run ThreadPool thread just for a couple of lines (create request, send request), after await it returns back to the client code, ie back to the loop. It is better to leave the single thread for firing requests, so Task.Run is redundant. Testing on Manjaro Linux - both variants work the same way. OPs problem is not reproduced though.

From my tests, it seems that IO completion port threads are being exhausted where the max available IO threads are 1000 (I wrote a simple code to find that out). But I did not figure out yet why Parallel.ForAsync has resolved that issue. Looks like it has better thread management but I need to dive deeper in it to understand how it works.

Yes it monitors the threadpool and throttles back before exhaustion. IOCP threads are managed by the threadpool.

I got an answer to my question on git hub https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/101411 I will post this as an answer a bit later
